# Clicking an element with Selenium results in a different result than with my brower

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working on scraping some generic public data from a site, but when I fill out the elements in the form (from and to dates) and fire the "Go" button, it seems to return one set of results vs the other. I think it has to do with a maybe cloudflare thing but I'm not sure.

The code in question:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("redacted now that I figured it out")

#enter from date
fromField = driver.find_element(By.ID, "from")
fromField.send_keys("5/23/2022")

#enter to date
toField = driver.find_element(By.ID, "to")
toField.send_keys("5/23/2022")

searchButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "submitButton")
searchButton.click()
```

Within the page, I can see:

```
<input class="btn submitButton" type="submit" onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; getResults();" value="Go">
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out, that this site in question had a weird javascript validation when you clicked out of a data field.

Clicking the search button did not qualify this validation, but if after sending the keys, I used toField.click(), it fires the validation and everything works. So strange though.